# want to create custom unit in android studio

Tags: android, android-support-library

In Android Studio, I want to create a custom unit that will change its value according to the screen size. The same result can be achieved using LayoutParameters but setting height, width and the 4 margins for each and every widget will be really hectic. Is it possible to create a custom unit that I can use in XML the way dp is used? I want to achieve this functionality:

```
DisplayMetrics m = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(m);
int deviceWidth = m.widthPixels;
int deviceHeight = m.heightPixels;
double width =  (  1.0*560 / 1440 /160);//1440=pixel xl width 560=pixel xl dpi 160=base dpi
double mLayout = ( (width * deviceWidth) );
```

Now instead of LayoutParams, i need mLayout to be my custom unit in pixels.

Comment: `dp` is not a custom unit. It just scales to a scale-factor determined by the screen density.

Comment: Yeah dp is not a custom unit but I need a custom unit that can value acc to the screen size.

Comment: Simply put I have created a view. I want it to shrink or enlarge acc to the screen size. Dimensions in percentage is what I want. Fill parent or wrap content won't help

Comment: `Dimensions in percentage is what I want.` Then a *PercentRelativeLayout* is what you want.

Comment: Its not working.

Comment: You're not using it correctly. It's made so that its children scale proportionally, in percentage. And it follows the rules of a *RelativeLayout*. Which it extends, actually.

Answer (score 0):

I found constraining to guidelines to be working correctly as I expected. PercentRelativeLayout did not work correctly.For more info= https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html